# How to add images beside each other in index.js dropping script?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using a Age verify-er at the [this codepen](https://codepen.io/tairli/pen/aKaNGK).

The following is what I have sliding down from the top of the screen:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.age_verifier_id = "28915";
    $.age_verifier_ajax_url = "http://selectoil.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php";
    $.AgeVerifier({
        enabled: "1",
        mode: "age",
        minimum_age: "21",
        cookie_expiration: "365",
        animation: "slide",
        title: "Welcome to My website",
        text: "Please use the slider to verify your age",
        background: "#333",
        background_type: "color",
        background_image_url: "http://selectoil.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/icon-logo.png",
        text_color: "#ffffff",
        submit_text: "Enter",
        error_message: "You need to be at least [age] years old to continue.",
        safe_url: "",
        safe_url_enabled: "0"
    });
});
```

I'm trying to make two images 200px by 200px each slide down side by side each other above the "Welcome to my website" text and slides down following the same slide sequence

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use an external animation library.
There is a CSS only library called [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)
Then you can achieve your requirement like this:

```js
$('#btn').on('click', (e) => {
  $('#overlay').fadeOut();
});
```

```css
html,body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
#overlay {
  background-color: #1AB4A1;
  height: 100%;
  margin:0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

#welcomeContainer {
  padding:20px 0px 0px 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

#welcomeContainer img {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

#btn {
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.0/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="overlay">
  <div id="welcomeContainer" class="animated fadeInDownBig delay-1s">
    <a href="#" id="btn">confirm</a>
    <br/>
    <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/404.svg" />
    <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/404.svg" />
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  content behind
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, but will this add to the animation that already occurs?
Because I need them all to slide down and be view-able in the same overlay with the age text, then when the age is entered I need the logos to disappear just like the rest of the Age verify window overlay

Comment: I have updated the answer to fit your extended requirement